# Prove ${\lim_{x \to a} e^{x} = e^{a}}$ with a $\delta-\epsilon$ argument

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

$\displaystyle{|x-a|< \delta}$

$\displaystyle{|e^{x} - e^{a}|< \epsilon}$
$⟺\displaystyle{\ln|e^{x} - e^{a}|< \ln\epsilon}$ 
$⟺\displaystyle{\frac{x}{a} < \ln\epsilon}$

if $a$ > 0

then $\displaystyle{x < a\ln\epsilon}$ 
$⟺\displaystyle{x-a<a (\ln\epsilon - 1)}$
$⟺\displaystyle{x-a \leq |x-a| < \delta}$

Choose $\delta$ < $a\ln\epsilon$ such that $x-a<a (\ln\epsilon - 1)$

if $a$ < 0

then $\displaystyle{x > a\ln\epsilon}$
$⟺ \displaystyle{x-a>a (\ln\epsilon - 1)}$
$⟺ \displaystyle{\delta > x-a \geq |x-a| }$

Choose $\delta$ < $a\ln\epsilon$ such that $x-a>a (\ln\epsilon - 1)$

Is this correct?

Comment: $\ln|e^x-e^a|\neq |\ln(e^x)-\ln(e^a)|$

Comment: oh yeah right... that was dumb

Comment: It's hard to tell which of your lines are goals, which are assumptions, which are deductions from previous lines. Without those connective words, a reader (or grader) can't really tell whether the proof is correct or not.

Comment: How do you define $\exp(x)$? Do you know this function is continuous?

Comment: For proving such fundamental facts, you have to tell us which definition of $e^x$ you're using. Because for example, using the power series definition it is "almost obvious".

Comment: $\ln|e^x - e^a| \ne \frac xa$ either.